# R plot_ly add_trace & add_text: error bar duplicates

Tags: r, plotly

I create in R with plot_ly a bar plot. I want the bars to have a text (displaying their value) and with an error bar (from the same data frame). All gets well introduced, but the error bar duplicate:

```
SampleData <- data.frame(Year = c(2014, 2014, 2015, 2015), Name = c("P", "J", "P", "J"),
    Results = c(7, 8, 6, 7), Error = c(1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.7))
SampleData <- split(SampleData, SampleData$Year)
```

If I make the plot of 2014, with the error bar and the Results as text:

```
SamplePlot <- plot_ly(SampleData[[1]], x = ~Name, y = ~Results, type = "bar",
   text = ~Results, error_y = list(type = "data", array = ~Error, color = "black")) %>%
add_text(textposition = "top right")
```

[image]

I then try to add a trace to plot_ly, with the same format and error bar:

```
SamplePlot <- add_trace(SamplePlot, data = SampleData[[2]], y = ~Results, type = "bar",
    text = ~Results, error_y = list(type = "data", array = ~Error, color = "black")) %>%
add_text(textposition = "top right")
```

This plot will have well-placed error bars, but also other between the result bars

[image]

Is there a way to do the `add_trace` with `error_y` and `add_text`, but without duplicating those error bars?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `add_annotations(showarrow=F)` instead. You can specify new `x` and `y` values for a better position.

Comment: Thanks @jimbou !
`add_annotations` works well, but how can I define their `x`position? That axis doesn't have a numerical reference so it put the values in the center of the name. For example, in this case, text to aligned to _J_ ; how could I split the 2014 and 2015 value?
Thanks!

Comment: It is not the nicest way, but will work, as categories are converted to numbers for `x` and `y` values you can set set `x=c(0,1)`. You have to play around with the values